# Ascending Pea Pattern generator

Tags: code-golf, math

For those who are not familiarized with the [Pea Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pea_pattern), it is a simple mathematical pattern.

**There are multiple variations of this pattern, but we will focus in one:**

> Ascending  Pea Pattern

It looks like this:

```
1
11
21
1112
3112
211213
...
```

It seems really hard to get the following line, but it is really easy. The way to get the next line is by counting the number of times a digit have repeated on the previous line (start counting with the lowest, to largest):

```
one
one one
two ones
one one, one two
three ones, one two
two ones, one two, one three
...
```

**Requirements/Rules:**

- We will start at `1`
- It will be a snippet
- There must be a way to specify the number of lines generates (e.g `5`
  will give the first 5 lines)
- The code should be as *short* as possible
- It must start counting from lowest to largest (the Ascending
  variation)

Comment: I am new here, please tell me how can I improve. For example, should I specify a date limit?

Comment: You could specify whether you want a full program with I/O or a snippet is enough (or if you don't care.)  But it looks well-specified enough at first glance.

Comment: @JB Thanks for your enlightening words. I have updated my post

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2323/look-and-say-sequence

Comment: The 13th iteration, and all subsequent iterations, are `21322314`.  Is this correct?

Comment: @JoeyAdams That's what I get, and the wiki page linked above seems to confirm it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## APL, 32 characters

```
⍪⌽({⍵,⍨,/{⌽⍵,+/⍵⍷d}¨⍳⌈/d←⊃⍵}⍣⎕)1
```

This generates lines starting from 0 (i.e. `0` generates `1`, `1` generates `1` followed by `1 1`, etc.), as specified by user input. I used Dyalog APL for this, and `⎕IO` should be set to its default of 1.

Example:

```
      ⍪⌽({⍵,⍨,/{⌽⍵,+/⍵⍷d}¨⍳⌈/d←⊃⍵}⍣⎕)1
⎕:
      0
1

      ⍪⌽({⍵,⍨,/{⌽⍵,+/⍵⍷d}¨⍳⌈/d←⊃⍵}⍣⎕)1
⎕:
      13
               1 
             1 1 
             2 1 
         1 1 1 2 
         3 1 1 2 
     2 1 1 2 1 3 
     3 1 2 2 1 3 
     2 1 2 2 2 3 
     1 1 4 2 1 3 
 3 1 1 2 1 3 1 4 
 4 1 1 2 2 3 1 4 
 3 1 2 2 1 3 2 4 
 2 1 3 2 2 3 1 4 
 2 1 3 2 2 3 1 4
```

Once I get some more time, I'll write up an explanation. ⍨

Answer (score 3):

### Python (2.x), <strike>81</strike> 80 characters

```
l='1'
exec"print l;l=''.join(`l.count(k)`+k for k in sorted(set(l)))\n"*input()
```

All tips or comments welcome!

```
usage: python peapattern.py
15 # enter the number of iterations
1
11
21
1112
3112
211213
312213
212223
114213
31121314
41122314
31221324
21322314
21322314
21322314
```

Answer (score 2):

### J, <strike>60</strike> <strike>46</strike> <strike>39</strike> 26 characters

```
1([:,(#,{.)/.~@/:~)@[&0~i.
```

**Edit 3**: Came up with a much nicer way of expressing this.

```
1([:;[:|."1[:/:~~.,.[:+/"1[:~.=)@[&0~i.
```

**Edit 2**: Finally found a way to move the argument to the end of the sequence and get rid of the unnecessary assignment stuff.

Previously:

```
p=.3 :'([:,[:|."1[:/:~~.,.[:+/"1[:~.=)^:(i.y)1
```

**Edit 1**: Fixes the output which should be `y` rows rather than the `y`th row. Also shortens things a bit. Shame about the `0`s, can't seem to get rid of the damn things.

Usage:

```
   1([:,(#,{.)/.~@/:~)@[&0~i. 1
1

   1([:,(#,{.)/.~@/:~)@[&0~i. 6
1 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 2 0 0
3 1 1 2 0 0
2 1 1 2 1 3

   1([:,(#,{.)/.~@/:~)@[&0~i. 10
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 2 0 0 0 0
3 1 1 2 0 0 0 0
2 1 1 2 1 3 0 0
3 1 2 2 1 3 0 0
2 1 2 2 2 3 0 0
1 1 4 2 1 3 0 0
3 1 1 2 1 3 1 4
```

Admittedly the usage is uglier now, but prettiness isn't the name of the game here...

Comment: This will be hard to beat with any 'traditional language'. Maybe golfscript or similar is up to the task ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 83

I'm pretty sure some Perl guru could outdo this, but here goes:

```
$_++;$n=<>;for(;$n--;){print$_.$/;$r='';$r.=length($&).$1 while(s/(.)\1*//);$_=$r;}
```

Expanded:

```
$_++;$n=<>;

for(;$n--;)
{
    print $_.$/;

    $r='';$r .= length($&).$1 while (s/(.)\1*//);  # The magic
    $_=$r;
}
```

Number of rows is passed in via STDIN.

Comment: Not quite a guru, I'm sure there are even shorter ways to be found, but 46 using pretty much the same method: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbQujixUqdYX0NPM8ZQS19FzbauUlFRMVlPxVA/NV2hPCMzJ1VXV8Ut2iD2/3@Tf/kFJZn5ecX/dRML/uv6muoZGBoAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 116

```
import Data.List
main=interact(unlines.map(show=<<).($iterate((>>=
 \x->[length x,head x]).group.sort)[1]).take.read)
```

Usage:

```
$ runhaskell pea.hs <<< 15
1
11
21
1112
3112
211213
312213
212223
114213
31121314
41122314
31221324
21322314
21322314
21322314
```

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, 140 characters

```
(defun m(x)
  (labels((p(l n)
    (if(= 0 n)
       nil
       (cons l
             (p(loop for d in(sort(remove-duplicates l)#'<)
                  append(list(count d l)d))
               (1- n))))))
    (p'(1) x)))
```

This is Lisp, so the function returns a list of lists. (m x) generates X sublists.

Answer (score 1):

#### Mathematica, 70

```
NestList[FromDigits@TakeWhile[DigitCount@#~Riffle~Range@9,#>0&]&,1,#]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>13</strike> 11 bytes (Feedback appreciated)

```
1ṢŒrUFƲÐ¡ṖY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//MeG5osWSclVGxrLDkMKh4bmWWf///zU)

```
1ṢŒrUFƲÐ¡ṖY
1     Ʋ         starting with 1, run these 4 links...
 ṢŒr            Ṣort the list and get the Œrun-length encoding of it,
    U           reverse each member of the RLE list (so it goes [repetitions, digit] instead of [digit, repetitions]),
     F          and Flatten the RLE list-of-lists to just a list of digits, which is the next number.
       Ð¡       do that (input) number of times,
         ṖY     Ṗop the last line off the output (an extra line is always calculated) and then print the numbers, separated by newlines.
```

Comment: `U€` can just be `U`, it vectorizes down to the row level. Then you can save another byte inlining `ṢŒrUF`, using `Ʋ` (last 4 links as monad): `1ṢŒrUFƲÐ¡ṖY`

Comment: Thanks again so much for the improvements @Lynn! Always nice to go from a string of 5+ links to 4 so you can use that quick.

Comment: You're welcome! (Tiny note: `ṢŒrU€FƲ` would have worked just fine -- it rolls [`Ṣ`, `Œr`, `U€`, `F`] into a monad. Maybe my use of "then" was a little misleading ^^; Similarly, in something like `abc$de$fƲ` will operate on the 4 links [`a`, `bc$`, `de$`, `f`] and roll them into a monad. This is the sense in which you can think of quicks as "parse-time stack operators": their outcome is pushed back onto a stack, and acts as if it were one link for future quicks.)

Comment: @Lynn I see, thank you again! Getting a lot better at "counting" links now, was able to completely inline [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164221/48718) and save a byte thanks to your comment!