# Square-free semiprime counting

Tags: code-golf, primes, fastest-code, counting

### Definition

> A square-free semiprime is a natural number that is the product of two distinct prime numbers.

### The task

Given a natural number `n`, count all square-free semiprimes less than or equal to `n`.

### Details

Please write a function or procedure that accepts a single integer parameter and counts all square-free semiprimes less than or equal to its parameter. The count must either be a return value of a function call or be printed to STDOUT.

### Scoring

The answer with the fewest number of characters wins.

In the event of a tie, the following criteria will be used in order:

1. <strike>Tallest person</strike>
2. Best [time-complexity](/questions/tagged/time-complexity)
3. Worst [space-complexity](/questions/tagged/space-complexity)

### Examples

```
f(1)     = 0
f(62)    = 18
f(420)   = 124
f(10000) = 2600
```

Comment: http://oeis.org/A180074 ?

Comment: oops, sorry, but no that sequence is not quite right due to the congruence restriction (e.g., 35=5*7 and 55=5*11 are not included). I will add a few example solutions to this particular problem momentarily.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A006881

Comment: What happens if a language doesn't have STDOUT (like javascript)? Use `console.log`?

Comment: @Inkbug isn't javascript capable of returning a value from a function?

Comment: @ardnew Oh, I missed that. Sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### J, <strike>50</strike> <strike>40</strike> <strike>38</strike> 37 characters

```
f=:3 :'+/y<:}.~.,(~:/**/)~p:i._1&p:y'
```

Usage:

```
   f 1
0
   f 62
18
   f 420
124
   f 10000
2600
```

With thanks to [FUZxxl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/134/fuzxxl).

**Performance test**

```
   showtotal_jpm_ ''[f 1[start_jpm_ ''
 Time (seconds)
┌───────┬──────┬────────┬────────┬─────┬────┬───┐
│name   │locale│all     │here    │here%│cum%│rep│
├───────┼──────┼────────┼────────┼─────┼────┼───┤
│f      │base  │0.000046│0.000046│100.0│100 │1  │
│[total]│      │        │0.000046│100.0│100 │   │
└───────┴──────┴────────┴────────┴─────┴────┴───┘
   showtotal_jpm_ ''[f 1[f 62[start_jpm_ ''
 Time (seconds)
┌───────┬──────┬────────┬────────┬─────┬────┬───┐
│name   │locale│all     │here    │here%│cum%│rep│
├───────┼──────┼────────┼────────┼─────┼────┼───┤
│f      │base  │0.000095│0.000095│100.0│100 │2  │
│[total]│      │        │0.000095│100.0│100 │   │
└───────┴──────┴────────┴────────┴─────┴────┴───┘
   showtotal_jpm_ ''[f 1[f 62[f 420[start_jpm_ ''
 Time (seconds)
┌───────┬──────┬────────┬────────┬─────┬────┬───┐
│name   │locale│all     │here    │here%│cum%│rep│
├───────┼──────┼────────┼────────┼─────┼────┼───┤
│f      │base  │0.000383│0.000383│100.0│100 │3  │
│[total]│      │        │0.000383│100.0│100 │   │
└───────┴──────┴────────┴────────┴─────┴────┴───┘
   showtotal_jpm_ ''[f 1[f 62[f 420[f 10000[start_jpm_ ''
 Time (seconds)
┌───────┬──────┬────────┬────────┬─────┬────┬───┐
│name   │locale│all     │here    │here%│cum%│rep│
├───────┼──────┼────────┼────────┼─────┼────┼───┤
│f      │base  │0.084847│0.084847│100.0│100 │4  │
│[total]│      │        │0.084847│100.0│100 │   │
└───────┴──────┴────────┴────────┴─────┴────┴───┘
   showtotal_jpm_ ''[f 1[f 62[f 420[f 10000[f 50000[start_jpm_ ''
 Time (seconds)
┌───────┬──────┬────────┬────────┬─────┬────┬───┐
│name   │locale│all     │here    │here%│cum%│rep│
├───────┼──────┼────────┼────────┼─────┼────┼───┤
│f      │base  │5.014691│5.014691│100.0│100 │5  │
│[total]│      │        │5.014691│100.0│100 │   │
└───────┴──────┴────────┴────────┴─────┴────┴───┘
```

I'm no theoretician as has been seen here in the past, but I think the time complexity is something like O(n<sub>p</sub><sup>2</sup>) where n<sub>p</sub> is the number of primes up to and including the input number n. This is based on the assumption that the complexity of my method (generating a very large multiplication table) far outweighs the complexity of the prime generating function built in to J.

**Explanation**

`f=:3 :'...'` declares a (monadic) verb (function). The input to the verb is represented by `y` within the verb definition.

`p:i._1&p:y` The `p:` verb is the multi purpose primes verb, and it's used in two different ways here: `_1&p:y` returns the number of primes less than `y` then `p:i.` generates every one of them. Using 10 as input:

```
   p:i._1&p:10
2 3 5 7
```

`(~:/**/)~` generates the table I spoke of earlier. `*/` generates a multiplication table, `~:/` generates a not-equal table (to eliminate the squares) and both of these are multiplied together. Using our previous output as input:

```
   */~2 3 5 7
 4  6 10 14
 6  9 15 21
10 15 25 35
14 21 35 49

   ~:/~2 3 5 7
0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0

   (~:/**/)~2 3 5 7
 0  6 10 14
 6  0 15 21
10 15  0 35
14 21 35  0
```

`}.~.,` now we turn the numbers into one list `,` get the unique values `~.` and remove the 0 at the start `}.`

```
   }.~.,(~:/**/)~2 3 5 7
6 10 14 15 21 35
```

`y<:` a comparison with the original input to check which values are valid:

```
   10<:6 10 14 15 21 35
1 1 0 0 0 0
```

`+/` and then sum that to get the answer.

```
   +/1 1 0 0 0 0
2
```

Comment: Do you have a phony version of this program (phony as the opposite of tacit)? 13 is not always giving the most efficient tacit code.

Comment: No, I didn't use 13 in this case - though I think I probably did what it would have done had I tried. The code is basically: `+/-.x<}.~.,(~:/~*[*/])p:i._1&p:[x=.n` where n is the input.

Comment: Why not just `f=:3 :'+/-.y<}.~.,(~:/~*[*/])p:i._1&p:y'` for 40 characters?

Comment: Thanks, I never even considered using `3 :'...'`

Comment: Would you publish some timing results so we can judge the efficiency of the program?

Comment: @DavidCarraher I've added some performance stats.

Comment: Would you like to add some notes about the algorithm?

Comment: @FUZxxl I've added an explanation.

Comment: Lesser than-or-equal is `<:` fyi. Have a look at the [vocabulary](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d012.htm) for more information.

Comment: @FUZxxl D'oh! Missed that. Always think of `<:` as decrement. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica <strike>65</strike> <strike>64</strike> <strike>55</strike> <strike>51</strike> <strike>47</strike> 39

**Code**

The following counts the number of  square-free semiprimes less than or equal to `n`:

```
FactorInteger@Range@n~Count~{a={_,1},a}
```

Any square-free semiprime factors into a structure of the form: `{{p,1}{q,1}}`
For example,

```
FactorInteger@221
(* out *)
{{13, 1},{17, 1}}
```

The routine simply counts the numbers in the desired range that have this structure of factors.

---

**Usage**

```
n=62;
FactorInteger@Range@n~Count~{a={_,1},a}

(* out *)
18
```

---

**Timing: All the given examples**

```
FactorInteger@Range@#~Count~{a = {_, 1}, a} & /@ {1, 62, 420, 10^4} // Timing

(* out *)
{0.038278, {0, 18, 124, 2600}}
```

---

**Timing: n=10^6**

It takes under four seconds to count the number of square-free semi-primes less than or equal to one million.

```
n=10^6;
FactorInteger@Range@n~Count~{a = {_, 1}, a}//Timing
(* out *)
{3.65167, 209867}
```

Comment: Fantastic, concise solution

Comment: @ardnew Thanks. I enjoyed the challenge.

Comment: Nice! Question: are those space characters around the `=` and after the `,` actually needed syntactically?

Comment: @ToddLehman,  You are right.  I removed them.  (They had not been counted so the byte count stays the same.)

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 115

```
r=range
p=lambda x:all(x%i for i in r(2,x))
f=lambda x:sum([i*j<=x and p(j)and p(i)for i in r(2,x)for j in r(2,i)])
```

Comment: `f=lambda x:sum([(i*j<=x)&p(j)&p(i)for i in r(2,x)for j in r(2,i)])` saves 5 characters.

Comment: @beary605: Thanks, but I think that it will take way too long without short circuiting.

Comment: voting you up. too many thoughts about `itertools` in my head.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ŒcfÆf€L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opOS0w21pj5rW@Pw/uudwO5Dh/v@/oY6CmZGOgomRAQA)

#### How it works

```
ŒcfÆf€L  Main link. Argument: n

Œc       Generate all 2-combinations of [1, ..., n], i.e., all pairs [a, b] such
         that 1 ≤ a < b ≤ n.
   Æf€   Compute the prime factorization of each k in [1, ..., n].
  f      Filter; keep only results that appear to the left and to the right.
      L  Take the length.
```

Comment: Wow, you made my attempt look embarrassing. Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 3):

### Python (139)

```
from itertools import*;s=lambda n:sum(x*y<=n and x<y for x,y in product(filter(lambda x:all(x%i for i in range(2,x)),range(2,n)),repeat=2))
```

Please provide some sample results so competitors could test their programs.

Comment: see, you didn't even need the examples! :^)

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby 82

```ruby
z=->n{[*2..n].select{|r|(2...r).all?{|m|r%m>0}}.combination(2).count{|a,b|a*b<=n}}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/cnm1Z

Answer (score 2):

## Python 139

```
def f(n):
 p=[];c=0
 for i in range(2,n+1):
    if all(i%x for x in p):p+=[i]
    c+=any((0,j)[i/j<j]for j in p if i%j==0 and i/j in p)
 return c
```

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript 64

```
~:ß,{:§,{)§\%!},,2=},0+:©{©{1$}%\;2/}%{+}*{..~=\~*ß>+\0?)+!},,2/
```

Online demo [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ewoKfjrDnyx7OsKnLHspwqdcJSF9LCwyPX0sMCs6wql7wql7MSR9JVw7Mi99JXsrfSp7Li5%2bPVx%2bKsOfPitcMD8pKyF9LCwyLwoKfTpmdW5jdGlvbgoKOycxJyBmdW5jdGlvbiBwCjsnNjInIGZ1bmN0aW9uIHAKOycxMDAnIGZ1bmN0aW9uIHA=&run=true)

***Note:** In the demo above I excluded the `420` and `10000` test cases. Due to the extremely inefficient primality test, it's not possible to get the program to execute for these inputs in less than 5 seconds.*

Answer (score 2):

### Shell, 40

```
#!/bin/sh

seq $1|factor|awk 'NF==3&&$2!=$3'|wc -l

#old, 61
#seq $1|factor|awk 'BEGIN{a=0}NF==3&&$2!=$3{a++}END{print a}'
```

Usage:

```
$ ./count 1
0
$ ./count 420
124
$ ./count 10000
2600
$ time ./cnt.sh 1000000
209867

real    0m23.956s
user    0m23.601s
sys     0m0.404s
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>14</strike> 13 bytes

```
RÆEḟ0⁼1,1$Ɗ€S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/ocJvrwx3zDR417jHUMVQ51vWoaU3w////TYwMAA)

```
RÆEḟ0⁼1,1$Ɗ€S    main function:
RÆE             get the prime factorization Exponents on each of the Range from 1 to N,
          Ɗ€    apply the preceding 1-arg function composition (3 funcs in a row) to each of the prime factorizations:
                (the function is a monadic semiprime checker, as per DavidC's algorithm)
    ḟ0          check if the factors minus the zero exponents...
      ⁼1,1$      ...are equal to the list [1,1]
             S   take the Sum of those results, or number of successes!
```

Constructive criticism welcomed!

Comment: This combination of `⁼` and `S` can be turned into a use of `ċ` (Count). You can get down to 10 bytes using it. I'll let you work it out!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2/3](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>95</s> 94 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(map(F,range(n+1)))
F=lambda x,v=2:sum(x%i<1and(F(i,0)or 3)for i in range(2,x))==v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEETP5iv2ImQxSBvFQzHXfoWXaFtdaDYhSUv79bGoODBzGN4wYc0vz7qQCz5mSGsSm4@pz7F/TDGR55EcZVlXm1AM5lZG6@6dBW7S5KSzQbYqWn72kg81IorW/IhFzUZ/qGVP19pyJ1tJqkIf4YTDlgTE8B1rtSAaM5d/Xyu4aAVnXSn43DdiFyJxBlIwSMLyBg)

Posted in a 6 year old challenge because it sets a new Python record, an IMO it's a pretty interesting approach.

## Explanation

```python
lambda n:sum(map(F,range(n+1)))           # Main function, maps `F` ("is it a semiprime?")
                                          #  over the range [0, n]
F=lambda x,v=2:                           # Helper function; "Does `x` factor into `v`
                                          #  distinct prime numbers smaller than itself?"
  sum(                                    # Sum over all numbers `i` smaller than `x`
    x%i<1                                 # If `i` divides `x`,
    and                                   #  then
    (F(i,0)                               #  add 1 if `i` is prime (note that `F(i,0)`
                                          #  is just a primality test for `i`!)
    or 3)                                 #  or `3` if `i` is not prime (to make `F`
                                          #  return `False`)
  for i in range(2,x))
  ==v                                     # Check if there were exactly `v` distinct prime
                                          #  factors smaller than `x`, each with
                                          #  multiplicity 1
```

## [Python 2/3 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), <s>88</s> <s>82</s> 81 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(sum(x%i<1and(x/i%i>0or 9)for i in range(2,x))==2for x in range(n+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYpBCsIwEADP@oq9FLIYsVlEsDS@xEukjS7YbYgtJK9P7aU9zByGCXn6jELnkEMu3j7L1w2vzoE0v3lQK6ni1jjpVLpwxY96jHBH/zcDC0Qn716RTojW0prTnuVkEMv2Gg030nClujkeQmSZgDV4xVgW)

Based on a 92-byte golf by Value Ink. PyPy is needed to correctly interpret `0or`, because standard Python sees this as an attempt at an octal number.

Comment: [92 bytes by checking square divisibility instead of primality](https://tio.run/##PU3bCsIwFHt2X3FehJ5ZZC0iONbXfYUv1W16YL3QdrB9fS1TDCSEkBC/pbezMpPxLiSIW6wKz3FMYXwuIZKzMxlKTDQFWE3qnmdtHoMG28bFMKM963nQ9jUyexKIWPXq11j3xnqkTmg7sKYrtq6lC3DDqSgBWfhOJV8RlZL5nwsOV8nhIhsO@3lbHXwgm4A4TIwwfwA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 61 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBCsMgFET3PcVf5qOlKqWb4D6HyEZEG8Hoj7G0UHp26ypkVvNm4JEp4fqk1vyQUH@tFqPPhUpY3UBa8X0rNaTaT37smyYmeboRt4whjvbX5hkmVxyEHUwC9zErRQfZw5LfUDNYEyPUxYF/JVtDTpeu6lo/SMSjP9QJ7kqcSIoexPYH)

```
f(n)={c=0;forprime(p=2,sqrtint(n),forprime(q=p+1,n/p,c++));c}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY8xC8IwEIX3/oobG1qxLeIiruIouHYJ5WoDaZJeUhTE316vUURB@qbw3nd3L06SWl3cNPlhlIQHQjxjr06kevSpEbCHewIsbRup08aOJrBXiF10W0tuRlPHZpWDHygoE3gwhwj8QANDLitzMGv3lc@Ki7Ps44n4el8hDCOZ13G2HkldwxEJQXmQBvAme6cRbAudvUKwwFU1hA6hHU0TlDUJF@Bafz9ZCrEUb6vlfFMVy0BZsISYpic)

```
squareFreeSemiPrimes(n) = {
    local(count = 0);
    forprime(p = 2, sqrtint(n), 
        forprime(q = p+1, n/p, 
            count++
        )
    );
    return(count);
}
\\ Here is an example of how to call the function
print(squareFreeSemiPrimes(1))
print(squareFreeSemiPrimes(62))
print(squareFreeSemiPrimes(420))
print(squareFreeSemiPrimes(10000))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>58</s> 45 bytes

*Thanks to Jo King for -13 bytes.*

```perl6
{+grep {3==.grep($_%%*)&&.all³-$_}o^*,1..$_}
```

Takes advantage of the fact that integers with four factors are either square-free semiprimes or perfect cubes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7v1o7vSi1QKHa2NZWD8TSUIlXVdXSVFPTS8zJObRZVyW@Nj9OS8dQTw/I@m/NlZZfpGBjqGBmpGBiZGCnoGunoBKvUM3FWZxYqaAEZAIFqtOAYrVKXLX/AQ)

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7v1o7vSi1QKHa2NZWD8TSUIlXVdXSVFPTS8zJObRZVyW@Nj9OS8dQTw/I@m/NlZZfpGBjqGBmpGBiZGCnoGunoBKvUM3FWZxYqaAEZAIFqtOAYrVKXLX/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ßº@N¬Që↔
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e1a7404eaa51891d&i=1%0A62%0A420%0A10000&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
F       for 1..n run the rest of the program
  :F    get distinct prime factors
  2(    trim/pad factor list to length 2
  :*    compute product of list
  _/    integer divide by initial number (yielding 0 or 1)
  +     add to running total
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=F+++%09for+1..n+run+the+rest+of+the+program%0A++%3AF%09get+distinct+prime+factors%0A++2%28%09trim%2Fpad+factor+list+to+length+2%0A++%3A*%09compute+product+of+list%0A++_%2F%09integer+divide+by+initial+number+%28yielding+0+or+1%29%0A++%2B+%09add+to+running+total&i=1%0A62%0A420%0A10000&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
{≥ḋĊ≠}ᶜ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wv/pR59KHO7qPdD3qXFD7cNuc//@jDXXMjHRMjAx0DA2AIBYA)

```
           The output is
{    }ᶜ    the number of ways in which you could
 ≥         choose a number less than or equal to
           the input
  ḋ        such that its prime factorization
   Ċ       is length 2
    ≠      with no duplicates.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 58 bytes

```
_
¶_$`
%(`$
$"
,,`_(?=(__+)¶\1+$)
¶1$'
)C`1(?!(__+)\1+¶)
2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvqpGgp82l9T@e69C2eJUELiBfhUtFiUtHJyFew95WIz5eW/PQthhDbRVNoApDFXUuTecEQw17RbAMUPzQNk0uo///DbnMjLhMjAwA)

Takes as input unary with `_` as tally mark

### Explanation

A number is a square-free semi-prime if its largest and smallest factor, excluding itself and 1, are both primes.

```
_
¶_$`
```

Takes the input and generate each unary number less than or equal to it, each on its own line

```
%(`
```

Then, for each number ...

```
$
$"
,,`_(?=(__+)¶\1+$)
¶1$'
```

Find its smallest and largest factor, excluding itself an 1 ...

```
)C`1(?!(__+)\1+¶)
```

and count the number of them that is prime. Since the smallest factor must be a prime, this returns 1 or 2

```
2
```

Count the total number of 2's

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>105</s> 104 bytes

```python
lambda m:sum(reduce(lambda(a,v),p:(v*(a+(n%p<1)),v>0<n%p**2),range(2,n),(0,1))[0]==2for n in range(m+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PclBCsIwEEDRtZ5iNsIknUUaxEVpvEjtItpEC2YaYhvw9DFQcPf5L37X18K6eHMrbxvuk4XQfbaAyU3bw@H@0FIWFDvMEm2DfIp9KwTlq@prS6kFJctPh5pYECqqOqjRGO2XBAwzw@6hqVL@c2gJLprgrNXYHQ8xzbwCE3hkUX4)

1 byte thx to [squid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85755/squid)

Comment: `(p*p)` can be `p**2`

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), chars 26, bytes 52

```
{≢b/⍨{(⍵≡∪⍵)∧2=≢⍵}¨b←π¨⍳⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{≢b/⍨{(⍵≡∪⍵)∧2=≢⍵}¨b←π¨⍳⍵}
  f 1
0
  f 9
1
  f 62
18
  f 420
124
  f 1000
288
  f 10000
2600
  f 100000
23313
```

this is a longer alternative  (59 chars that i would prefer)

```
r←h w;n;t
n←4⋄r←0
n+←1⋄→0×⍳w<n⋄→2×⍳(2≠≢t)∨2≠≢∪t←πn⋄r+←1⋄→2
```

test:

```
  h 1000000
209867
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-rprime`, 64 bytes

I know that there's another Ruby solution here, but I didn't want to bump it with comments since it was answered in 2012... and as it turns out, [using a program flag counts it as a different language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/52194), so I guess this technically isn't "Ruby" anyhow.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cur1rDUE8vT1MvOb80r6S6JrMm1zZTr6AoMzc1PiWzLLM4Mz/POlevOLMqtQZIleZqqFnlJBaXaNraGtXW/i9QSItWidcryY/PjP1vyGVmxGViZMBlaAAE//ILSoCai//rFoGN@6@bBwA)

**Explanation**

```ruby
->n{(1..n).count{|i|m=i.prime_division;m.size|m.sum(&:last)==2}}
->n{                                    # Anonymous lambda
    (1..n).count{|i|                    # Count all from 1 to `n` that match
                                        # the following condition
                m=i.prime_division;     # Get the prime factors of `i` as
                                        #  base-exponent pairs (e.g. [2,3])
                m.size                  # Size of factors (# of distinct primes)
                      |                 # bit-or with...
                       m.sum(&:last)    # Sum of the last elements in the pairs
                                        #  (the sum of the exponents)
                                    ==2 # Check if that equals 2 and return.
                                        # Because 2 is 0b10, the bit-or means
                                        #  that the condition is true iff both
                                        #  are either 2 or 0, but because this
                                        #  is a prime factorization, it is
                                        #  impossible to have the number of
                                        #  distinct primes or the sum of the
                                        #  exponents to equal 0 for any number
                                        #  > 1. (And for 1, size|sum == 0.)
    }                                   # End count block
}                                       # End lambda
```