# Is it a Sphenic Number?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem, primes

A Sphenic Number is a number that is the product of exactly three distinct primes. The first few Sphenic numbers are `30, 42, 66, 70, 78, 102, 105, 110, 114`. This is sequence [A007304](https://oeis.org/A007304) in the OEIS.

### Your Task:

Write a program or function to determine whether an inputted integer is a Sphenic number.

### Input:

An integer between 0 and 10^9, which may or may not be a Sphenic Number.

### Output:

A truthy/falsy value indicating whether the input is a Sphenic Number.

### Examples:

```
30  -> true
121 -> false
231 -> true
154 -> true
4   -> false
402 -> true
79  -> false
0   -> false
60  -> false
64  -> false
8   -> false
210 -> false
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Is `60` a sphenic number? `2 × 2 × 3 × 5`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer that's not the product of 3 distinct primes though, that's the product of 3 distinct and 1 duplicate prime.

Comment: @Riker I'm not really sure if "3 distinct primes" means "3 primes that are all distinct" or "when uniquified there should remain 3 primes". EDIT: Oh I see, `60` isn't a sphenic number. (waiting for OP clarification)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer According to the definition of sphenic numbers, 60 is not one of them.  I do not know however if 60 is valid for this challenge.

Comment: @WheatWizard, 60 is not a sphenic number (e.g. output/return falsy).

Comment: Can we output a falsy value if the input is sphenic and a truthy value if not?

Comment: @No, sorry.  Strictly Sphenic=truthy.

Comment: You should add a test case with 4 or more prime factors like `210`

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6869/square-free-semiprime-counting)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>6</s> 3 bytes

```
ḋ≠Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO7kedCx7uXPX/v5Gx4X8A)

#### Explanation

```
ḋ        The prime factorization of the Input…
 ≠       …is a list of distinct elements…
  Ṫ      …and there are 3 elements
```

Comment: And then there's the one language which has a builtin like `≠`.

Comment: And the builtin `Ṫ` as well.

Comment: @Zacharý `Ṫ` is not really a built-in predicate though; it is a built-in variable: a list of 3 variable elements. It's a fairly useful pre-constrained variable in many different challenges.

Comment: Congratulations on the shortest answer.

Answer (score 12):

### bash, 43 bytes

```sh
factor $1|awk '{print $2-$3&&$3-$4&&NF==4}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5NCsIwGET3PcVQPpJVoPlREdouXXqHNDa0qInUiAXr2WNwZlaPt5jBPqfsbELb8pWj99lbl@ICkpt9X8E/j2UOCaQEacZICzKMnU9dZ748r5UvasAcoBtIJaG0hNwZlDYKhyMa7MtMdYkVSkY3RYiAmgJEj/oPh3ICHhSKFUZscPH2uhch5R8)

Input via command line argument, outputs `0` or `1` to stdout.

Fairly self-explanatory; parses the output of `factor` to check that the first and second factors are different, the second and third are different (they're in sorted order, so this is sufficient), and there are four fields (the input number and the three factors).

Comment: You can remove the ` $1` because `factor` will take input from stdin if none is given on the command-line

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
_YF7BX=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Pz7Szdwpwvb/f0MDUwA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D8@0s3cKcL2v0vIf2MDLkMjQy4jY0MuQ1MTLiA0MOIyt@Qy4DIDIhMA).

#### Explanation

```
_YF   % Implicit input. Nonzero exponents of prime-factor decomposition
7     % Push 7
B     % Convert to binary: gives [1 1 1] 
X=    % Is equal? Implicit display
```

Comment: @Suever I was thinking about that, but then falsy ouput becomes uglier (either empty with error or an array with some zeros). Not sure if I should...

Comment: `X=` is the saddest builtin I've ever seen.

Answer (score 9):

## C, <s>88</s> <s>78</s> <s>126</s> <s>58</s> <s>77</s> 73 + 4 (`lm`) = 77 bytes

```c
l,j;a(i){for(l=1,j=0;l++<i;fmod(1.*i/l,l)?i%l?:(i/=l,j++):(j=9));l=i==1&&j==3;}
```

Ungolfed commented explanation:

```c
look, div; //K&R style variable declaration. Useful. Mmm.

a ( num ) { // K&R style function and argument definitions.

  for (
    look = 1, div = 0; // initiate the loop variables.
    look++ < num;) // do this for every number less than the argument:

      if (fmod(1.0 * num / look, look))
      // if num/look can't be divided by look:

        if( !(num % look) ) // if num can divide look
          num /= look, div++; // divide num by look, increment dividers
      else div = 9;
      // if num/look can still divide look
      // then the number's dividers aren't unique.
      // increment dividers number by a lot to return false.

  // l=j==3;
  // if the function has no return statement, most CPUs return the value
  // in the register that holds the last assignment. This is equivalent to this:
  return (div == 3);
  // this function return true if the unique divider count is 3
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBDoIwEADAr5gmJLu2COjJLg0f8dIslLRZwACejF@3kviAGS5H5pzFJPIQ8R2WFcQ1JrmaROs2UpiWHprLOVZiBLtYSGchVu4gWqOF5O6IJC45d6NPZpp8nOE/EbfXuiZ8rnHeA6ji1ttTsT1mZVhr44GxU/v6GpRVwcs2KDyKLwfx45ZLmX4)

Comment: Consider `i*1.0/l` instead of the cast to float. (And since `l`,`j` are global they are initialized to 0 for free, you don't need to do that if the function is only called once.  Not sure what the rule is for that.)

Comment: [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcxBDoIwEADAr5gmJK0tAnKyy4aPeGkWSrZZwACejF@3mjgPGConopzFJQiazSuumxZsXMIaxNqOIWGc10E3lzNX4sT0XEifvOYKxVmbjL8ZEEyILbwzwRx40f8IqLvWNZjHxssRtSrawZ@K/b4oR9a6oMn06tieo/IqBtlHZX7Fh6KEac@lzF8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ÆEḟ0⁼7B¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm@vDHfMNHjXuMXc6tOT////GBgA)

Uses Luis Mendo's algorithm.

Explanation:

```
ÆEḟ0⁼7B¤
ÆE       Prime factor exponents
  ḟ0     Remove every 0
    ⁼7B¤ Equal to 7 in base 2?
```

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
rimFz1=7Yb=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vygz163K0NY8Msn2/39DA1MA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f/T8nM9etytDWPDLJ9n@BYW36f2MDLkMjQy4jY0MuQ1MTLiA0MOIyt@Qy4DIDIhMA).

#### Explanation

Based on my MATL answer.

```
ri    e# Read integer
mF    e# Factorization with exponents. Gives a list of [factor exponent] lists
z     e# Zip into a list of factors and a list of exponents
1=    e# Get second element: list of exponents
7     e# Push 7
Yb    e# Convert to binary: gives list [1 1 1]
=     e# Are the two lists equal? Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ÆE²S=3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm@uhTcG2xv@P7jnc/qhpjfv//8YGOgqGRoY6CkbGQMLQ1ERHAYQMjHQUzC11FICyZiBsAgA)

#### How it works

```
ÆE²S=3  Main link. Argument: n

ÆE      Compute the exponents of n's prime factorization.
  ²     Take their squares.
   S    Take the sum.
    =3  Test the result for equality with 3.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
ÓnO3Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8OQ8f@PA//@NDQA)

Uses Dennis's algorithm.

Comment: `3Q` can be `Í` (pop `a`, push `a-2`) since only \$1\$ is truthy.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>81</s> <s>49</s> 46 bytes

Includes 6 bytes for command line options `-rprime`.

```rb
->n{n.prime_division.map(&:last)==[1]*3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOk@voCgzNzU@JbMsszgzP08vN7FAQ80qJ7G4RNPWNtowVsu49n@BQlq0kWWsDpAyNoBQhmDKBEoZxf7/l19QAtRf/F@3CGwiAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
≡ḋ3Ẋ≠p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1Hnwoc7uo0f7up61Lmg4P///8YGAA)

Returns 1 for sphenic numbers and 0 otherwise.

#### Explanation

```
≡ḋ3Ẋ≠p    Example input: 30
     p    Prime factors: [2,3,5]
   Ẋ≠     List of absolute differences: [1,2]
≡         Is it congruent to...       ?
 ḋ3           the binary digits of 3: [1,1]
```

In the last passage, congruence between two lists means having the same length and the same distribution of truthy/falsy values. In this case we are checking that our result is composed by two truthy (i.e. non-zero) values.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 31 bytes

```
SquareFreeQ@#&&PrimeOmega@#==3&
```

Comment: Since you're already testing for squarefree-ness, `PrimeNu` will do just as well as `PrimeOmega`, and is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
&{IPQq3lP
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26%7BIPQq3lP&input=30&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 7 bytes

```
w♂N13α=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/7/80cwmP0Pjcxtt//83NgAA)

Explanation:

```
w♂N13α=
w       Push [prime, exponent] factor pairs
 ♂N     Map "take last element"
   1    Push 1
    3   Push 3
     α  Repeat
      = Equal?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 59 bytes

```hs
f x=7==sum[6*0^(mod(div x a)a+mod x a)+0^mod x a|a<-[2..x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwtbc1ra4NDfaTMsgTiM3P0UjJbNMoUIhUTNRG8gDs7QN4qDMmkQb3WgjPb2K2Nj/uYmZebYFRZl5JSppCiYGRv8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
k
k@è¥X ÉÃl ¥3
```

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=awprQOilWCDJw2wgpTM=&inputs=MzA=,MTIx,MjMx,MTU0,NA==,NDAy,Nzk=,MA==,NjA=,NjQ=)

Comment: @Oliver That would result in passing a function to `Number.k()`, which would have no effect and just check if the input has 3 prime factors, not 3 *distinct* prime factors. That would mean `8` (with three prime factors: `2, 2, 2`) would pass despite not being in [A007304](https://oeis.org/A007304)

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was just going by the test cases.

Comment: @Oliver Yeah, that really threw me for a loop when working on this solution. I just added `8` to the test cases for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 bytes

```
7&(=2#.~:@q:)~*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1krBXE3D1khZr87KodBKs06Liys1OSNfQUNHL03JQFPB2EDB0MhQwcjYUMHQ1EQBCA2MFMwtFQwUzIDI5P9/AA)

### Explanation

```
7&(=2#.~:@q:)~*  Input: integer n
              *  Sign(n)
7&(         )~   Execute this Sign(n) times on n
                 If Sign(n) = 0, this returns 0
          q:       Prime factors of n
       ~:@         Nub sieve of prime factors
    2#.            Convert from base 2
   =               Test if equal to 7
```

Comment: Very nice use of ~: and #.  An alternative could be (7&(=#.@~:@q:)~*) which I find a little easier to read, but is no shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 26 bytes

```
⎕CY'dfns'
((≢,∪)≡3,⊢)3pco⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdOSM1Ofv/o76pzpHqKWl5xepcGhqPOhfpPOpYpfmoc6GxzqOuRZrGBcn5QCUg9f/BGriMDbi4ICxDI0MY08gYzjQ0NYExEQwDIxjT3BLGMoMbZGYCAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 44 bytes

```
Plus@@Last/@#==Length@#==3&@FactorInteger@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/IKe02MHBJ7G4RN9B2dbWJzUvvSQDxDJWc3BLTC7JL/LMK0lNTy1yUFb7H1CUmQdUl6bvUG1soKNgaGSoo2BkDCQMTU10FEDIwEhHwdxSRwEoawbCJrX/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(1>>n%k|7>>k*k%n*3for k in range(2,n))==6
```

*Thanks to @xnor for golfing off 1 byte!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoMwFETX7SlmE4zyCyaxSoXkJN1YWluJfiXqotC7pwbmzeINzPLdPjOb2MPiHsduejw7cLvuk1TOsfC/xjlfeMGF6ecAj4EROn6/pCbOc2vrmDwnb0qC0oqgzVHqWhFSSk1oboRjrRNVez4tYeBNZsLsuDiINYOAZEIvj9M8/gE)

Comment: You can check squarefreeness with `k*k%n` rather than `n%k**2`

Comment: Right, I only need one failure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**C, <strike>91</strike> 102 bytes, corrected (again), golfed, and tested for real this time:**

```
<strike>s(c){p,f,d;for(p=2,f=d=0;p<c&&!d;){if(c%p==0){c/=p;++f;if(c%p==0)d=1;}++p;}c==p&&f==2&&!d;}</strike>
s(c){int p,f,d;for(p=2,f=d=0;p<c&&!d;){if(c%p==0){c/=p;++f;if(c%p==0)d=1;}++p;}return c==p&&f==2&&!d;}
```

/* This also works in 93 bytes, but since I forgot about the standard rules barring default int type on dynamic variables, and about the not allowing implicit return values without assignments, I'm not going to take it:

```
p,f,d;s(c){for(p=2,f=d=0;p<c&&!d;){if(c%p==0){c/=p;++f;if(c%p==0)d=1;}++p;}p=c==p&&f==2&&!d;}
```

(Who said I knew anything about C? ;-)

Here's the test frame with shell script in comments:

```
/* betseg's program for sphenic numbers from 
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h> /* compile with -lm */

/* l,j;a(i){for(l=1,j=0;l<i;i%++l?:(i/=l,j++));l=i==1&&j==3;} */
#if defined GOLFED
l,j;a(i){for(l=1,j=0;l++<i;fmod((float)i/l,l)?i%l?:(i/=l,j++):(j=9));l=i==1&&j==3;}
#else 
int looker, jcount;
int a( intval ) {
  for( looker = 1, jcount = 0; 
    looker++ < intval; 
    /* Watch odd intvals and even lookers, as well. */
    fmod( (float)intval/looker, looker )  
      ? intval % looker /* remainder? */
        ? 0 /* dummy value */
        : ( inval /= looker, jcount++ /* reduce the parameter, count factors */ ) 
      : ( jcount = 9 /* kill the count */ ) 
  )
    /* empty loop */;
  looker = intval == 1 && jcount == 3; /* reusue looker for implicit return value */
}
#endif

/* for (( i=0; $i < 100; i = $i + 1 )) ; do echo -n at $i; ./sphenic $i ; done */
```

I borrowed betseg's previous answer to get to my version.

This is my version of betseg's algorithm, which I golfed to get to my solution:

```
/* betseg's repaired program for sphenic numbers
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int sphenic( int candidate )
{
  int probe, found, dups;
  for( probe = 2, found = dups = 0; probe < candidate && !dups; /* empty update */ ) 
  { 
    int remainder = candidate % probe;
    if ( remainder == 0 ) 
    {
      candidate /= probe;
      ++found;
      if ( ( candidate % probe ) == 0 )
        dups = 1;
    }
    ++probe;
  } 
  return ( candidate == probe ) && ( found == 2 ) && !dups;
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) { /* Make it command-line callable: */
  int parameter;
  if ( ( argc > 1 ) 
       && ( ( parameter = (int) strtoul( argv[ 1 ], NULL, 0 ) ) < ULONG_MAX ) ) {
    puts( sphenic( parameter ) ? "true" : "false" );
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}

/* for (( i=0; $i < 100; i = $i + 1 )) ; do echo -n at $i; ./sphenic $i ; done */
```

Comment: Does it answer the question, now?

Comment: Yes, it does. Insert this to link to betseg's answer: `[betseg's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135203/65836)`. You can also click edit on his answer to suggest an edit to it, if you want, that would include the explanation - no promises on whether it'll be approved or not.

Comment: I'm here now, and I fixed my program, it's at 87 bytes now; but your program looks good too.

Comment: @betseg Interesting that you used floating point this time. Oh, and thanks for letting me borrow your algorithm. ;-)

Comment: @JoelRees i added explanation to my answer, also your answer has a problem i think? it doesn't seem to work correctly: [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##RY7LCoMwEAB/pQ0YEhJpam@uS3@kF9m4IqhdjD2Jv970deh1YIahsifKWTz7CMmQ3fi@GMHKM0YMIA1pfYxgt4ENFYIY7EYnFHCO4c8inmF3TmAnRNGaEauvuGeCqR1m8ysDNVUIYGUZ5pWNKi6xPhTpNitPzvnPwVWty6NTteJ2TJ2y78STeGz7lMtxegE)

Comment: reason of floats: 105 = 3*5*7, but 105/2%2 = 0.5, which C interprets as 0.

Comment: @betseg I think I called the working uncompressed version and missed the errors mixed with the warnings. (Want to blame it on my pre-C89 compiler, but that's on the other side of the ocean. :-/) I'll fix my code and my count. Nice test rig you have.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 23 bytes

```
0:`((~.-:]*.3=#)@q:)@.*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P91WT0HBwCpBQ6NOT9cqVkvP2FZZ06HQStNBT4urAChpbKBgZGyoYGhqomBiYMSVBhSyUDA0MlQwUTC3VDBQMAMiEwWu1OSMfIV0hQIYI@3/fwA)

Handling 8 and 0 basically ruined this one...

`q:` gives you all the prime factors, but doesn't handle 0.  the rest of it just says "the unique factors should equal the factors" and "the number of them should be 3"

Comment: This fails for input `60`

Comment: @ConorO'Brien thanks.  See my edit -- fixing 60 _helped_, but i realized i also wasn't handling 0 correctly, and handling that more than doubles the bytes

Comment: The last one was my original idea, and that fails for `8`.

Comment: I have `(6=]#@,~.)@q:` as a possible solution

Comment: @ConorO'Brien ah good point about 8.  yours will fail for 0, though.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien well, i fixed all the edge cases, it can hardly be considered golf anymore... sigh.

Comment: ``(6=]#@,~.)@(0:`q:@.*)`` for 21

Comment: @ConorO'Brien, nice.  `(6=]#@,~.)` is some clever exploitation of the parsing rules.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>135</s> 121 bytes

- Quite long since this includes all the procedures: prime-check, obtain-prime factors and check sphere number condition.

```python
lambda x:(lambda t:len(t)>2and t[0]*t[1]*t[2]==x)([i for i in range(2,x)if x%i<1and i>1and all(i%j for j in range(2,i))])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYwxDsIwEAR7XnFNpDtE4bi0cD7iuDBKAheZS2K5MK83JKJANLtbzM76yo9FdN1sX2N43oYAxeB3ZRNHwUydDjJAdsqfs2v30N7aQugYpiUBAwukIPcR9aUQT1Aavrb7ibujQozIzXzQ8y/NRJ7qv0QpMif4eDZkMmtiycD1DQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
lambda x:6==sum(5*(x/a%a+x%a<1)+(x%a<1)for a in range(2,x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCyszWtrg0V8NUS6NCP1E1UbtCNdHGUFNbA0Kn5RcpJCpk5ikUJealp2oY6VRoav4vKMrMK1FI0zAxMNL8DwA)

Comment: This gives false positives like 48. I had been trying the same thing.

Comment: @xnor Fixed, but at the cost of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 87 bytes

```
n=>(a=(p=i=>i>n?[]:n%i?p(i+1):[i,...p(i,n/=i)])(2)).length==3&&a.every((n,i)=>n^a[i+1])
```

Example code snippet:

```js
f=
n=>(a=(p=i=>i>n?[]:n%i?p(i+1):[i,...p(i,n/=i)])(2)).length==3&&a.every((n,i)=>n^a[i+1])

for(k=0;k<10;k++){
  v=[30,121,231,154,4,402,79,0,60,64][k]
  console.log(`f(${v}) = ${f(v)}`)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 66 bytes:

```php
for($p=($n=$a=$argn)**3;--$n;)$a%$n?:$p/=$n+!++$c;echo$c==7&$p==1;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/285093bffbdb0bb5f7ac3cb1125b6bbb91c4f5e1).

Infinite loop for `0`; insert `$n&&` before `--$n` to fix.

**breakdown**

```php
for($p=($n=$a=$argn)**3;    # $p = argument**3
    --$n;)                  # loop $n from argument-1
    $a%$n?:                     # if $n divides argument
        $p/=$n                      # then divide $p by $n
        +!++$c;                     # and increment divisor count
echo$c==7&$p==1;            # if divisor count is 7 and $p is 1, argument is sphenic
```

**example**
argument = `30`:
prime factors are `2`, `3` and `5`
other divisors are `1`, 2*3=`6`, 2*5=`10` and 3*5=`15`
their product: `1*2*3*5*6*10*15` is `27000` == `30**3`

Answer (score 1):

## J, <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 19 bytes

Previous attempt: `3&(=#@~.@q:)~*`

Current version: `(*/*3=#)@~:@q: ::0:`

## How it works:

```
(*/*3=#)@~:@q: ::0:  Input: integer n
               ::0:  n=0 creates domain error in q:, error catch returns 0
            q:       Prime factors of n
         ~:@         Nub sieve of prime factors 1 for first occurrence 0 for second
(*/*3=#)@            Number of prime factors is equal to 3, times the product across the nub sieve (product is 0 if there is a repeated factor or number of factors is not 3)
```

This passes for cases 0, 8 and 60 which the previous version didn't.

Comment: why not 3=#~.q:     for 7characters? From a J session  3=#~.q: 30 ==> 1     and 3=#~.q: 20 ==> 0

Comment: Richard, your suggestion gives a false positive for n=60 and creates a domain error for n=0, but my previous version failed for n=60 as well. Your comment prompted me to strive for a correct solution!

Answer (score 1):

## VB.NET (.NET 4.5), 104 bytes

```
Function A(n)
For i=2To n
If n Mod i=0Then
A+=1
n\=i
End If
If n Mod i=0Then A=4
Next
A=A=3
End Function
```

I'm using the feature of VB where the function name is also a variable. At the end of execution, since there is no return statement, it will instead pass the value of the 'function'.

The last `A=A=3` can be thought of `return (A == 3)` in C-based languages.

Starts at 2, and pulls primes off iteratively. Since I'm starting with the smallest primes, it can't be divided by a composite number.

Will try a second time to divide by the same prime. If it is (such as how 60 is divided twice by 2), it will set the count of primes to 4 (above the max allowed for a sphenic number).

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##hdJRS8MwEAfw596nOPYgK1JJ02xjDxGCOhhYXxz44ku3ZXrQXaBNxW9fY1UMKCRvCb/8udzljfqhaYt909OhYOuLs2M31u44tBbrEm7pjIRNj8Tevthu3Ax88OQYzZxz2LgOScudQ4btCRnDzXAgdq@WwVzqEvhZE9zxEbenPwKNVvBg3z0YbXQ1sZ/8MXsc9lg3xJBlN45719qrp468vSe281klEItrnOFFqKQSeQ4Zfq9/dCnLXx02CS6riIdNKn2hovSFSnCFUelJLGSEhUzw1TrKXq0TWsSVpHq4jDu@TGoV6@mVn@MNQ53G/PXDxg8)

Comment: -2 bytes by [using `n\i=n/i` instead of `n Mod i=0`](https://tinyurl.com/3bnbtnzh). But is it fair to put `Dim i as integer` in the header when it's required for the function to work? [`Function A(n%)`](https://tinyurl.com/23cfbhxw) costs +1 byte. But if external `Dim` statements are allowed, then -7 bytes by [pseudo-boolean arithmetic](https://tio.run/##Nc85DsJADAXQenwKlwkQSFhKFyMWCYnQgERDA4wBo@CRsiBuH4at9fd/lh/H5ORLbnPvmoIxz2Amd5Sew0OFojVfuGwXjZ5q8Yo20hgWvkSh4dajgiPdC@lAwCbkQPcUZYnEHdfNYHnGX4jbK4cyjWHNzxosWRrBXB3@4dZsmiPmB1Ew5u3fkDDFcGKSpmFkgmWjW/yFpl4rX3B/V0rNK1EOSVj62ObNBuzDf59qXw).

Comment: @Deadcode When I was writing it in Visual Studio, I didn't need to `Dim i` at all; I could use it directly in the loop. Putting it in the header was just to get the Mono implementation that Try It Online was using to compile.

The shortening for Mod looks awesome though. I'll be sure to add that in!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 80 bytes

```js
n=>(p=(n,f=2)=>n%f?p(n,f+1):f,(a=p(n))<n&&(b=p(n/=a))<n&&(c=p(n/=b))==n&a<b&b<c)
```

Using a recursive function to get the smaller factor.
Output 1 if sphenic, false if there are 2 or less factors and 0 otherwise

**Test**

```js
F=
n=>(p=(n,f=2)=>n%f?p(n,f+1):f,(a=p(n))<n&&(b=p(n/=a))<n&&(c=p(n/=b))==n&a<b&b<c)

;[30,121,231,154,4,402,79,0,60,64,8,210].forEach(
  x=>console.log(x,F(x))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, <s>51</s> <s>49</s> <s>48</s> <s>46</s> <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```
1∊((w=×/)∧⊢≡∪)¨(⊢∘.,∘.,⍨){⍵/⍨2=≢∪⍵∨⍳⍵}¨⍳w←⎕
```

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B1%u220A%28%28w%3D%D7/%29%u2227%u22A2%u2261%u222A%29%A8%28%u22A2%u2218.%2C%u2218.%2C%u2368%29%7B%u2375/%u23682%3D%u2262%u222A%u2375%u2228%u2373%u2375%7D%A8%u2373w%u2190%u2375%7D30&run) (modified so it can run on TryAPL)

I wanted to submit one that doesn't rely on the dfns namespace whatsoever, even if it is **long**.

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (ECMAScript), 46 bytes

```
^((?=(xx+?)\2*$)(?=(x+)(\3+$))\4(?!\2+$)){3}x$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/BbsIwEER/BSIEu6QJCdAecE1OPXDh0B6bVrJgcdwax7INpFC@PQ2VKvU2ozfS6H2Io/Abp2xIvFVbcvvafNJX67ihU@@Z5FNjAc58ORm37wAFh6aJCyyn4wH@thihnMUDxHIORb@c3uJldm0G7XhyxjTUL8EpIwFTr9WG4OEumSMyzzN2qpQmAM0dia1WhgCxz81Ba7xIrlNvtQowSkbI1A7AcJlqMjJUuJx@fyu/FmtQ3ArnaWUCyNfsDfEP0H9glnmRL24YQ@XqU7QyR6HVtueEkbToRbFmu9oBU4@cmIpj7A6jJkodWRIBFKZ7ETYVuE7OD4e2Uwpws8iZPQQfXDdh12ubJfl9lv0A)

This works similarly to [Match strings whose length is a fourth power](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19262/match-strings-whose-length-is-a-fourth-power/21951#21951) and very similarly to part of [Is this a consecutive-prime/constant-exponent number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/164911/is-this-a-consecutive-prime-constant-exponent-number/179412#179412):

```
^
(                   # Loop the following:
    (?=(xx+?)\2*$)  # \2 = smallest prime factor of tail
    (?=
        (x+)(\3+$)  # \3 = tail / {smallest prime factor of tail}; \4 = tool to make tail = \3
    )\4             # tail = \3
    (?!\2+$)        # assert that tail is no longer divisible by \2
){3}                # Execute the loop exactly 3 times
x$                  # assert tail == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 9 bytes

```
Ƒsfç⁼lp3=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWa49NLE47vPxR456cAmPbJcVJycVQmQWLzC0gLAA)

Explanation:

```
Ƒ          # unique prime factors
 s         # swap so input is back on top
  f        # prime factors
   ç       # apply each to the stack, and wrap results:
    ⁼      #   exactly equal?
     l     #   length
      p    # product
       3=  # equal to 3?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
ǐ₌ÞuL*3=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLHkOKCjMOedUwqMz0iLCIiLCIxMTAiXQ==)

Seems Vyxal always beats Thunno 2 by just a byte or two...this is basically the same as my Thunno 2 answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 96 bytes

```
f(k)=0^{(3-∑_{n=2}^k0^{mod(k,n)}sgn(∏_{d=3}^nmod(n,d-1))log_n(gcd(k,n^{ceil(log_nk)}))^2)^2}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8zvx2x85ax)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kon1aqnj14)

Port of [Dennis's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135275/96039) so make sure to upvote that one too. There is probably a shorter way to go about this though, but this is the most straightforward way I saw that could easily be ported to Desmos.

I might put a longer explanation on how this works if I have time.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 43 bytes

```arturo
$=>[x∧3=size x:=unique<=<=factors.prime&]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?ZHktyV)

Simply asks "are its prime factors unique and are there three?"

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 43 bytes

```
{3==grep ->\a{a.is-prime&&$_%%(a^a*a)},^$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2tjWNr0otUBB1y4msTpRL7NYt6AoMzdVTU0lXlVVIzEuUStRs1YnTiW@9r@1QnFipQJYtVqajkKckYGB9X8A)

The `grep` produces a list of the numbers `a` up to, but not including, the argument to the function `$_`, such that:

- `a` is prime (`a.is-prime`); and
- exactly one of `a` and `a*a` (`a ^ a*a`) divide the argument.

The latter condition excludes prime factors that occur in multiplicities of higher than one.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <s>66</s> 57 bytes

```
Length@#1==3&&And@@EqualTo[1]/@#2&@@(FactorInteger@#)&
```

Defines an anonymous function.

`` is [Transpose](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Transpose.html).

### Explanation

`FactorInteger` gives a list of pairs of factors and their exponents. E.g. `FactorInteger[2250]=={{2,1},{3,2},{5,3}}`. This is transposed for ease of use and fed to the function `Length@#1==3&&And@@EqualTo[1]/@#2&`. The first part, `Length@#1==3`, checks that there are 3 unique factors, while the second, `And@@EqualTo[1]/@#2` checks that all the exponents are 1.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 99 bytes

```
def s(n):a,k=2,0;exec('k+=1-bool(n%a)\nwhile not n%a:n/=a;k+=10**9\na+=1\n'*n);return k==3*10**9+3
```

First submission. Forgive me if I did something wrong.
Kinda silly, counts the number of factors of `n`, and then the number of times `n` is divisible by each (by adding 10**9).

I'm pretty sure there are a few easy ways to cut off ~10-20 characters, but I didn't.

Also this is *intractably* slow at 10**9. Could be made *okay* by changing `'...a+=1\n'*n` to `'...a+=1\n'*n**.5`, as we only need to go to the square root of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 34 bytes

```
n->if(n,moebius(n)*omega(n)==-3,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYvNCsIwEIRfZegpKxvIT1U8pC8iHiK0JWC3oerBp48bmBm@YZiaj2LX2hakJnYqixHe9vlZvm8jdNq3ec0KKdnIjlqu9fUzAjuhHkU@ikMvA/RIxLhHx/DBM0LU8OeR0eUC43pj6HrpHh/U/g)

Answer (score 0):

### Forth, 153

```
: w swap ;
: d 2dup ;
: o rot ;
: sp 0 w 1 
begin 1+ d mod 0= if w over / w d mod 0= if o 16 + o o then o 1+ o o then 
d > 0= until drop 1 = w 3 = and ;
```

( 153 including spaces. Spaces are required delimiters in Forth. )

( Test frame for compressed version: )

```
: testsp
  0 do i 8 .r space
    i sp if ." true" else ." false" then
    cr
  loop
;
```

( This uses a corrected version of [betseg's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135203/65836).)

( Uncompressed, with comments: )

```
: sphenic ( n -- f )
  0 ( counter )
  swap 1 ( counter n probe )
  begin
    1+ ( increment probe )
    2dup mod ( Remainder? )
    0= if
      swap over / ( reduced-n )
      swap ( bring probe back )
      2dup mod 0= if 
        rot 128 + rot rot
      then
      rot 1+ rot rot ( count and put count back )
    then ( counter reduced-n probe )
    2dup > 0= 
  until
  drop 1 = 
  swap 3 = and
;

: testsphenic
  0 do i 8 .r space
    i sphenic if ." true" else ." false" then
    cr
  loop
;
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 172 Bytes

I'd appreciate improvement suggestions:

```
n=>{var r=Enumerable.Range(2,n).Where(i=>Enumerable.Range(2,i-2).All(a=>i%a!=0));return r.SelectMany(x=>r.SelectMany(y=>r.Select(z=>x==z|x==y|y==z?-1:x*y*z))).Contains(n);}
```

With formatting:

```
n =>
{
    var r = Enumerable.Range (2, n).Where (i => Enumerable.Range (2, i - 2).All (a => i % a != 0));
    return r.SelectMany (
        x => r.SelectMany (
            y => r.Select (z => x == z | x == y | y == z ? -1 : x * y * z))).Contains (n);
}
```

And as whole programm:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;


namespace S
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main ()
        {
            Func<int, bool> s =
                    n =>
                    {
                        var r = Enumerable.Range (2, n).Where (i => Enumerable.Range (2, i - 2).All (a => i % a != 0));
                        return r.SelectMany (
                            x => r.SelectMany (
                                y => r.Select (z => x == z | x == y | y == z ? -1 : x * y * z))).Contains (n);
                    }
                ;

            for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                if (s (i))
                    Console.WriteLine (i);
            Console.ReadLine ();
        }
    }
}
```

If you add the byte count of the using directives (which are needed for the code to compile), you'd get **203 Bytes**.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/Jfk5/0)

Comment: Would you be to make a function with a single letter name for `Enumerable.Range(2, m)`? You call it twice, and it might save some bytes.

Comment: @BrianJ The idea doesn't sound bad, but I don't know how I'd do it. Is it possible to define methods inside of statement lambdas?

Comment: You can, but I forgot how verbose it becomes. Quick and dirty, I got `Func<int, IEnumerable<int>> e = a => { return Enumerable.Range(2, a); };`, plus another `using`.

Answer (score 0):

## C#7 122 bytes

```
bool F(int n){int P(int m,int f=2)=>m%f>0?P(m,f+1):f;int a,b,c;return(a=P(n))<n&&(b=P(n/=a))<n&&(c=P(n/=b))==n&a<b&b<c;}
```

porting of my JS answer