# Look-and-say: Conway revisited

Tags: code-golf

You should all be familiar with the [Conway sequence (a.k.a. 'look-and-say'-sequence)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) by now:

```
     1
    11
    21
  1211
111221
312211
etc
```

You can also start by any arbitrary number as starting point. Let `f(s)` be the next element of the sequence. Now for every given `s`we can find `f(s)`. The reverse is not as trivial: it is not for every `y` possible to find the predecessor `s` such that `f(s) = y`. E.g. for `y = 1` we cannot find a predecessor. But if `y` has an *even* length you can divide it into pairs of digits which describe each one part of a predecessor:

```
513211 divides in 51,32,11
so: 51 comes from 11111 
    32 comes from 222
    11 comes from 1
put together: 111112221
```

So this way there we can define an *unique* predecessor for every `y` of even length.

**Note**: The 'predecessor' `s` defined this way does generally NOT satisfy `f(s) = y`.

### Goal

Write a function / program snippet that accepts a string of digits as input that

- calculates the next element of the Conway sequence if the length of the input string is *odd*
- calculates the predecessor of the input string as defined above if the input string length is *even*.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

**Recent Questions based on the look-and-say sequences:**

- [Look and say sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2323/look-and-say-sequence)
- [Point-free look and say sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23790/point-free-look-and-say-sequence)
- [Quickly find length of n-th term of the look-and-say sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8431/quickly-find-length-of-n-th-term-of-the-look-and-say-sequence)

Comment: I'm confused. Can you explain how `513111` divides into `51`, `32` and `11`?

Comment: I feel like this is a combined duplicate of some look and say sequence challenge and a run-length decoding challenge (I'm sure we had those).

Comment: What would the predecessor of `11111111111111` be? According to your spec, it would be `1111111`. You should modify your specification to define a reasonable answer for this.

Comment: @TheBestOne `11111111111111` simply has no predecessor. It's an illegal input.

Comment: @TheBestOne Yes this is correct, I defined an arbitrary rule for the predecessor that does not always match a 'real' predecessor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## CJam, <s>46</s> <s>45</s> <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```
l_,2%{0\{@)@@_2$=!{0\0}*;}*\)\}{2/{(~*}%}?
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) It takes the number on STDIN and prints the result to STDOUT.

Comment: `si` -> `~` = 45

Comment: @Optimizer Thanks, I forget you can eval a character.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <del>125 120 119</del> 101 bytes

```rb
f=->n{c=n.chars;(n.size%2>0?c.chunk{|x|x}.map{|a,b|[b.size,a]}:c.each_slice(2).map{|a,b|b*a.hex})*''}
```

String input taken through function `f`:

```rb
f['111221']    # => "1211"
f['513211']    # => "111112221"
f['111112221'] # => "513211"
```

Expanded with notes:

```rb
# define lambda that takes one arg
f = -> (n) {
  # store digits in c
  c = n.chars

  # n is of odd length
  if n.size % 2 > 0
    # group identical numbers
    c.chunk{ |x| x }.map do |a, b|
      # array of [digit count, digit value]
      [b.size, a]
    end
  else
    # slice array into groups of two elements
    c.each_slice(2).map do |a, b|
      # repeat the second digit in a pair
      # the first digit-times.
      b * a.hex
    end
  end * '' # join array
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Prolog - 170 bytes

```
[]/[].
T/R:-0*_*T*R.
C*X*[X|T]*R:-(C+1)*X*T*R.
C*X*T*Y:-10*C+X+Y+R,T/R.
N+R+A:-N=:=0,A=R;D is N mod 10,N//10+R+[D|A].
F-C-R:-C/N,(N=F,R=C;F-N-R).
[1]-[1,1]. S-T:-S-[1]-T.
```

This snipped defines the function `(-)/2`. You can invoke it like

```
?- [1,1,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,1]-T.
T = [1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1] .

?- [1]-T.
T = [1, 1] .
```

There seems to be only one [lengths in this sequence](http://oeis.org/A005341) with an odd parity: the initial `[1]`.

```
wr_len :- wr_len(1, [1]).
wr_len(N, Cur) :-
    length(Cur, Len),
    TrailingZeroes is lsb(Len),
    (TrailingZeroes > 0 -> Par = 'even'; Par = 'odd'),
    writef('%t\t%t\t%t\t%t\n', [N, Len, Par, TrailingZeroes]),
    get_next(Cur, Next),
    succ(N, O),
    !, wr_len(O, Next).
```

```
% index, length, parity of length, num of trailing 0 in bin presentation of length
?- wr_len.
1       1       odd     0
2       2       even    1
3       2       even    1
4       4       even    2
5       6       even    1
6       6       even    1
7       8       even    3
8       10      even    1
9       14      even    1
10      20      even    2
11      26      even    1
12      34      even    1
13      46      even    1
14      62      even    1
15      78      even    1
16      102     even    1
17      134     even    1
18      176     even    4
19      226     even    1
20      302     even    1
21      408     even    3
22      528     even    4
23      678     even    1
24      904     even    3
25      1182    even    1
26      1540    even    2
27      2012    even    2
28      2606    even    1
29      3410    even    1
30      4462    even    1
31      5808    even    4
32      7586    even    1
33      9898    even    1
34      12884   even    2
35      16774   even    1
36      21890   even    1
37      28528   even    4
38      37158   even    1
39      48410   even    1
40      63138   even    1
41      82350   even    1
42      107312  even    4
43      139984  even    4
44      182376  even    3
45      237746  even    1
46      310036  even    2
47      403966  even    1
48      526646  even    1
49      686646  even    1
50      894810  even    1
51      1166642 even    1
52      1520986 even    1
53      1982710 even    1
54      2584304 even    4
55      3369156 even    2
56      4391702 even    1
57      5724486 even    1
58      7462860 even    2
59      9727930 even    1
ERROR: Out of global stack
% I added a few "strategic" cuts (`!`) to get so far.
```

Readable:

```
get_next([], []).
get_next(Current, Next) :-
    get_next_sub(0, _, Current, Next).

get_next_sub(Length, Digit, [Digit|Tail], Result) :-
    get_next_sub(Length+1, Digit, Tail, Result).
get_next_sub(Length, Digit, Further, Result) :-
    number_to_list(10*Length+Digit, Result, ResultTail),
    get_next(Further, ResultTail).

number_to_list(Number, Result, Accumulator) :-
    0 is Number -> Result = Accumulator;
    Digit is Number mod 10,
    number_to_list(Number // 10, Result, [Digit|Accumulator]).

get_previous(Stop, Current, Result) :-
    get_next(Current, Next),
    (   Next = Stop
    ->  Result = Current
    ;   get_previous(Stop, Next, Result)
    ).

get_prev_or_next(Input, Result) :-
    length(Input, Length),
    (   1 is Length mod 2
    ->  get_next(Input, Result)
    ;   get_previous(Input, [1], Result)
    ).
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python: 139 chars

```
import re
f=lambda s:''.join(['len(b)'+a for a,b in re.findall(r'((\d)\2*)',s)] if len(s)%2 else map(lambda a,b:b*int(a),s[::2],s[1::2]))
```

single test case

```
print f('1111122221111222112')
>>> 514241322112
print f('514241322112')
>>> 1111122221111222112
```

Comment: You can remove the space from `s)] if` to `s)]if`.

Comment: You can also remove the space in between `2 else`

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <strike>134 128</strike> 115

```
n=length
l x=x#mod(n x)2
(a:b:c)#0=replicate(read[a])b++c#0
(a:b)#1=(\(c,d)->show(1+n c)++a:d#1)$span(==a)b
_#_=[]
```

If it needs to be from stdin/stdout, add `main=interact l` for <strike>150 144</strike> 131 total chars.  The function is called `l`.

```
*Main> putStr . unlines $ map (\x->x++":\t"++l x) ([replicate n '1'|n<-[5..10]]++map show [0,6..30]++map show [n*n+n|n<-[2..10]])
11111:  51
111111: 111
1111111:    71
11111111:   1111
111111111:  91
1111111111: 11111
0:  10
6:  16
12: 2
18: 8
24: 44
30: 000
6:  16
12: 2
20: 00
30: 000
42: 2222
56: 66666
72: 2222222
90: 000000000
110:    2110
```

Comment: Could you please provide usage example? While I got `l "11"` to work, I get an exception with `l "111"` or `l "1111111111111"`

Comment: @PaulGuyot, Seems like fixing that cut a few chars off my score.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl - 98 bytes

The size of all these control statements bugs me, but I'm pretty happy with how the regexes worked out.

```pl
($_)=@ARGV;if(length()%2){$\=$&,s/^$&+//,print length$&while/^./}else{print$2x$1while s/^(.)(.)//}
```

Uncompressed:

```pl
($_)=@ARGV;
if(length()%2)
{
$\=$&, #Assigning the character to $\ causes it to be appended to the print (thanks, tips thread!)
s/^$&+//, #Extract the string of characters
print length$& #Print its length
while/^./ #Get next character into $&
}else{
print$2x$1
while s/^(.)(.)//
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## **Java 7, Score = <del>252</del> 235 bytes**

Yep, it's java again; the worst golfing language in the world. This approach uses strings. Arbitrarily large integers are supported in java but would take much more room to code in.

Call with `f(intputString)`. Returns the corresponding string.

Golfed:

```java
String f(String a){char[]b=a.toCharArray();a="";int i=0,j=0,d=0,e=b.length;if(e%2==0)for(;i<e;i+=2)for(j=0;j<b[i]-48;j++)a+=b[i+1];else{for(;i<e;i++)d=d==0?(j=b[i]-48)*0+1:b[i]-48!=j?(a+=d+""+j).length()*--i*0:d+1;a+=d;a+=j;}return a;}
```

Golfed Expanded with structure code:

```java
public class LookAndSayExpandedGolfed{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new LookAndSayExpandedGolfed().f(args[0]));
    }

    String f(String a){
        char[]b=a.toCharArray();
        a="";
        int i=0,j=0,d=0,e=b.length;
        if(e%2==0)
            for(;i<e;i+=2)
                for(j=0;j<b[i]-48;j++)
                    a+=b[i+1];
        else{
            for(;i<e;i++)
                d=d==0?(j=b[i]-48)*0+1:b[i]-48!=j?(a+=d+""+j).length()*--i*0:d+1;
            a+=d;
            a+=j;
        }
        return a;
    }

}
```

Partially Golfed:

```java
public class LookAndSayPartiallyGolfed{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new LookAndSayPartiallyGolfed().f(args[0]));
    }

    String f(String a){
        char[] number = a.toCharArray();
        String answer = "";
        int i, j, longestStreakLength = 0;
        if (number.length % 2 == 0){
            for (i = 0; i < number.length; i += 2)
                for (j = 0; j < number[i] - 48; j++)
                    answer += number[i+1];
        } else{
            j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++)
                longestStreakLength = longestStreakLength == 0 ? (j = number[i] - 48) * 0 + 1 : number[i] - 48 != j ? (answer += longestStreakLength + "" + j).length()*--i*0 : longestStreakLength + 1;
            answer += longestStreakLength;
            answer += j;
        }
        return answer;
    }

}
```

Completely expanded:

```java
public class LookAndSay{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new LookAndSay().function(args[0]));
    }

    String function(String a){
        char[] number = a.toCharArray();
        if (number.length % 2 == 0){
            String answer = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i += 2){
                for (int j = 0; j < number[i] - '0'; j++){
                    answer += number[i+1];
                }
            }
            return answer;
        }
        String answer = "";
        int longestStreakLength = 0;
        int longestStreakNum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
            if (longestStreakLength == 0){
                longestStreakNum = number[i] - '0';
                longestStreakLength = 1;
                continue;
            }
            if (number[i] - '0' != longestStreakNum){
                answer += longestStreakLength;
                answer += longestStreakNum;
                longestStreakLength = 0;
                i--;
            } else {
                longestStreakLength++;
            }
        }
        answer += longestStreakLength;
        answer += longestStreakNum;
        return answer;
    }

}
```

To run, first compile the second entry with: `javac LookAndSayExpandedGolfed.java`

Then run with: `java LookAndSayExpandedGolfed`

**Edit:** Fixed error.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)`

Comment: @KenzieTogami Fixed.

Comment: I don't think so, is `--1` supposed to be `--i`?

Comment: @KenzieTogamie Yes, it is. It's fixed now.

Comment: Cool, that works. The reverser fails, however. `513211` -> `11111`.

Comment: As soon as you fix that (or if I do while I try to golf this more) I compressed the current one to 233.

Comment: @KenzieTogami Fixed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19073/discussion-between-kenzie-togami-and-thebestone).

Answer (score 2):

## Erlang, 205

```
f(L)->g(L,L,[]).
g([A,B|T],L,C)->g(T,L,lists:duplicate(A-$0,B)++C);g([],_,R)->R;g(_,L,_)->i(L,[]).
h([A|T],A,N,B)->h(T,A,N+1,B);h(L,B,N,C)->i(L,integer_to_list(N)++[B|C]).
i([H|T],A)->h(T,H,1,A);i(_,R)->R.
```

Main function is f, taking the input as an Erlang string and returning the output as a string as well.

```
f("11"). % returns "1"
f("111"). % returns "31"
f("1111111111111"). % returns "131"
```

The function can be made 15 bytes shorter (190) by dropping the more than 9 identical characters case requirement. `f` calls `g` which computes the predecessor recursively, and if the number of characters is odd (found at when computation ends), it calls function `i` which, paired with `h`, computes the next element.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 105

```
import Data.List
l=length
c r|odd$l r=group r>>=(l>>=(.take 1).shows)|x:y:z<-r=[y|_<-['1'..x]]++c z|0<1=r
```

I think it's nice it turned out not using any helper functions :-).

Comment: `|x:y:z<-r` - I totally did not know you could do that. That's so cool!

Comment: @Flonk Its called "pattern guards". It used to be an extension and in one of the versions of Haskell it was added :-)

Comment: This makes a lot of things so much easier. You learn something new every day! :)

Answer (score 2):

### APL (45)

```
∊{2|⍴⍵:(⊃,⍨⍕∘⍴)¨⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵⋄/⍨∘⍎/¨⌽¨⍵⊂⍨1 0⍴⍨⍴⍵}
```

Yes, that's a valid function definition, even with the `∊` on the outside.

```
      ∊{2|⍴⍵:(⊃,⍨⍕∘⍴)¨⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵⋄/⍨∘⍎/¨⌽¨⍵⊂⍨1 0⍴⍨⍴⍵}'513211'
111112221
      ∊{2|⍴⍵:(⊃,⍨⍕∘⍴)¨⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵⋄/⍨∘⍎/¨⌽¨⍵⊂⍨1 0⍴⍨⍴⍵}'111112221'
513211
      f←∊{2|⍴⍵:(⊃,⍨⍕∘⍴)¨⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵⋄/⍨∘⍎/¨⌽¨⍵⊂⍨1 0⍴⍨⍴⍵}
      f ¨ '513211' '111112221'
┌─────────┬──────┐
│111112221│513211│
└─────────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (in-browser, ES5, IE8+), 152

```
var s=prompt(),r='',n=r,c=r,i=0;do{c!=s[i]?(r+=n+c,n=1,c=s[i]):n++;i++}while(c)n='';i=0;while(s[i]){n+=Array(1*s[i]+1).join(c=s[i+1]);i+=2}alert(c?n:r)
```

Can be shortened by 4 chars if you skip var, or a few more chars with other intermediate unvarred globals too, but let's pretend we are not bad programmers for a minute.

Switching to ES6 short-syntax function with argument and return value instead of using prompt, alert for IO can save more.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/86L1w6Lk/

Comment: Don't worry about those `var`s... we're all "bad programmers" here. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 - 159 bytes

```
import re;l=input();x=len;print(''.join([str(x(i))+j for i,j in re.findall('((.)\2*)',l)]if x(l)%2 else[j*int(i)for i,j in[l[i:i+2]for i in range(0,x(l),2)]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Cobra - 217

(186 if I can assume a `use` statement for `System.Text.RegularExpressions` exists elsewhere)

```cobra
do(s='')=if((l=s.length)%2,System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.replace(s,(for x in 10 get'[x]+|').join(''),do(m=Match())="['[m]'.length]"+'[m]'[:1]),(for x in 0:l:2get'[s[x+1]]'.repeat(int.parse('[s[x]]'))).join(''))
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 85

Using regular expression replace with function. Different regexp and different function depending on input length being even or odd.

```
F=s=>s.replace((i=s.length&1)?/(.)(\1*)/g:/../g,x=>i?x.length+x[0]:x[1].repeat(x[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 78 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.size%2<1?s.gsub(/(.)(.)/){$2*$1.to_i}:s.gsub(/(.)\1*/){$&.size.to_s+$1}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3_XTtiquL9Yozq1JVjWwM7Yv10otLkzT0NfQ0gUhfs1rFSEvFUK8kPz6z1gpJMsZQCySpBtYJki7WVjGsrYWaqlJQWlKs4BatZGpobGRoqBTLBRMwBAEjIyOgGETtggUQGgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 18 (or 17?) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
S2ôø`s×IÅγs.ι‚JIgè
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9vc2FiaWX//1Myw7TDuGBzw5dJw4XOs3MuzrnigJpKSWfDqP//NTEzMjExMDA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/YKPDWw7vSCg@PL3ycOu5zcV653Y@apjlVZl@eMV/nf/RBjqGOoZAwlDHyEDHyFDH2EjHFMQGChkBBQ2NjECSQAooBSINgdLGCMoALAuSNzKMBQA).

Since the challenge asks for a string input, which by default allows for a list of characters, it would be 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) less by removing the leading `S`:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6PCWwzsSig9P9zzcem5zsd65nY8aZnl5ph9e8f9/tJKpko6SIRAbA7ERlA3CBmAcCwA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/o8NbDu9IKD48vfJw67nNxXrndj5qmOVVmX54xX@d/9HRSgZKsTrRSoZQUgfO14GKGcHFjOBixkCWEZhliqYOWT9EvQ6S2UZQjGyHDooMwnxUUZiMKZRnTKQMupvQsRGq3bEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
S        # Convert the (implicit) input to a list of digits
 2ô      # Split it into parts of size 2
   ø     # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
    `    # Pop and push both lists separately to the stack
     s   # Swap the two lists on the stack
         # (or swap it with the implicit input if the input was a single digit number)
      ×  # Repeat the digits the numbers amount of times (at the same positions of the
         # lists)
I        # Push the input again
 Åγ      # Run-length encode it, pushing the list of digits and list of lengths
         # separately to the stack
   s     # Swap those two lists on the stack
    .ι   # Interleave the two lists into one:
         #  [a,b,c,...] and [d,e,f,...] → [a,d,b,e,c,f,...]
‚        # Pair the two lists together
 J       # Join both inner lists to a number
  I      # Push the input yet again
   g     # Pop and push its length
    è    # Modular 0-based index it into the pair
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```